# WinSocket2 в c#

Tags: c#

Вопрос в следующем: Как использовать winSocket2 в c#. Как подключить и как использовать.

Ссылки приветствуются)
В интернете искал, но там меня отсылали к System.Net. Задача в том что мне нужно использовать именно winSocket2.  Если это все же одно и тоже, то не нужно минусовать пост и говорить что я плохо искал и отправлять меня в поиск, а просто скажите то да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке C# не используется WinSock непосредственно, но его функциональность копируют классы в пространстве имен System.Net, в частности класс Socket. Фактически, используя System.Net с другими возможностями C# вы получите такую же функциональность, как если бы использовали WinSock.

Но если по каким-то причинам Вам нужен именно WinSock используемый С/С++, то придется напрямую взаимодействовать с ws2_32.dll и городить что-то подобное: [Winsock in C#](http://www.elitepvpers.com/forum/co2-programming/159327-advanced-winsock-c.html)